# "Undefined variable: laplace" in SCILAB 5.5.2 and 6.1.1

Tags: symbolic-math, scilab

My versions of SCILAB are 5.5.2 and 6.1.1 but I can't find the module that contains laplace, if I try to use it it says:
"  !--error 4
Undefined variable: laplace"

I tried to use: "exec('Loadsignal.sci')"
but it returns:
"                       !--error 241
File "Loadsignal.sci" does not exist"

What else can I do?

Comment: I guess your script uses the Scimax toolbox (https://gitlab.com/scilab/forge/scimax). However, this toolbox is not maintained any more.

Comment: @Horacio Barrios : could you post your former script, in order to get information on your context?

Comment: I don't have a script per se, I was just in the console, typed "s=%s" and "t=%t" and proceeded to type "laplace(t)"